# FindBugs warning: Inefficient use of keySet iterator

Tags: java, iterator, sonarqube, treemap, findbugs

This a a similar question to [[FindBugs warning: Inefficient use of keySet iterator instead of entrySet iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12639259/findbugs-warning-inefficient-use-of-keyset-iterator-instead-of-entryset-iterato][1])

However, there I am trying to do something a little different. My current code is here:

```
for (Double key2 : sortedPolygons.keySet()) {
    if (sortedPolygons.get(key2).getExteriorRing().equals(hole)) {
        sortedPolygons.remove(key2);
        break;
    }
}
```

Doing something like the solution in the link does not work. Here is an implementation of said solution:

```
for(Map.Entry<Double, Polygon> entry : sortedPolygons.entrySet()) {
    if (entry.getValue().getExteriorRing().equals(hole)) {
         .....
```

The problem here is that I am trying to *delete* the entry. There is no `entry.remove()`. How can I replace my first block of code, without the FindBugs error:

> **Inefficient use of keySet iterator instead of entrySet iterator** ->
>
> This method accesses the value of a Map entry, using a key that was
>   retrieved from a keySet iterator. It is more efficient to use an
>   iterator on the entrySet of the map, to avoid the Map.get(key) lookup.

To note, the underlying structure is `TreeMap`, and it cannot be changed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I fail to understand your reasoning: in the first snippet, you use

```
sortedPolygons.remove(key2);
```

to remove a key. Nothing prevents you to do the same in the second snippet:

```
sortedPolygons.remove(entry.getKey());
```

Whatever the way you iterate, this will lead to a `ConcurrentModificationException` anyway, because for most collections, you can't modify it while iterating on it, except by using its iterator.

Quote from [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html):

> The iterators returned by the iterator method of the collections returned by all of this class's "collection view methods" are fail-fast: if the map is structurally modified at any time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the iterator's own remove method, the iterator will throw a ConcurrentModificationException.

So the code should be:

```
for (Iterator<Map.Entry<Double, Polygon>> it = sortedPolygons.entrySet().iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
    Map.Entry<Double, Polygon> entry = it.next();
    if (entry.getValue().getExteriorRing().equals(hole)) {
        it.remove();
        // if you want to exit the loop as soon as you found a match:
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: the key isn't actually needed (see my answer)

Comment: @PeterLawrey: agreed. +1 to your answer. I'll leave my answer as is, to show the OP how to iterate over entries, just in case he needs the key in the future.

Comment: The OP was `break`ing after the `remove`. But +1 for using an `Iterator`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider: Now I see it. That's why he didn't get a ConcurrentModificationException. Very fragile though. I would still use an Iterator, which is also more efficient at removing anyway.

Comment: `sortedPolygons.remove(entry.getKey());` 
somehow didn't think of doing that, but is there a reason you don't use a for-each loop? Isn't there a way to do that in this situation? And is there a reason you removed the `break;`?

Comment: @DanGordon: If you want to break as soon as you found a matching value, then the break should be there. I didn't use the foreach loop because, without the break, that would cause a ConcurrentModificationException, as explained in the answer. The only safe way to remove elements while iterating is to remove the elements using the iterator. The foreach loop doesn't allow that.

Comment: It’s worth noting that you don’t need to use the `entrySet()` for that; every collection view supports removal. So here, you could use `for(Iterator<Polygon> it = sortedPolygons.values() .iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) if(it.next().getExteriorRing().equals(hole)) { it.remove(); break; }` If no short-circuiting is required, Java 8’s `sortedPolygons.values() .removeIf(poly -> poly.getExteriorRing().equals(hole));` would be even smoother.

Answer (score 4):

How about you use the entrySet() iterator as suggested.

```
for(Iterator<Map.Entry<Double, Ploygon>> iter = sortedPolygons.entrySet().iterator(); 
         iter.hasNext();) {
    Map.Entry<Double, Ploygon> entry = iter.next();

    if (condition)
        iter.remove();
}
```

However you don't need the key so you can just iterate the values

```
for(Iterator<Ploygon> iter = sortedPolygons.values().iterator(); 
         iter.hasNext();) {
    Ploygon ploygon = iter.next();

    if (condition)
        iter.remove();
}
```

Comment: Ah. I see. The key is being used only to iterate the values. So just *iterate the values*.

Comment: +1 for reminding me that you can remove the full entry using the value iterator.